# How can I convert `#lang reader "path/to/reader.rkt"` into `(module ...)` syntax?

Tags: syntax, module, racket

In [the Racket docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._hash-lang%29) I found the following explanantion:

> In the case of `#lang` racket, the syntax is
>
> ```
> #lang racket
> decl ...
> ```
>
> which reads the same as
>
> ```
> (module name racket
>   decl ...)
> ```

But how can I convert `#lang reader "path/to/reader.rkt"` syntax into `(module ...)` syntax, while not generating errors in DrRacket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can’t. `#lang` languages are strictly more powerful than module languages, and in fact they are a superset of module languages. A language defined with `#lang` simply provides a “reader” function, which accepts the body of a module as input and produces a `(module ...)` form as output.

For some languages in the Racket ecosystem, like `#lang racket/base` and `#lang racket`, this transformation from source to module is extremely simple. In the case of those languages, there is no difference between `#lang racket/base` and `(module m racket/base ...)`. However, for some other languages, the syntax is completely different—it might not even be s-expression based! For example, consider [Scribble](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/index.html) and its LaTeX-inspired syntax.

This means that `#lang`s have the power to control the *reader*, the piece of Racket that parses source code, while module languages only have the power to control the initial namespace of a module.